# Airplane hardlocked and rfkill do not work on lenovo thinkpad

Tags: wireless, lenovo, thinkpad, rfkill, airplane-mode

I have a problem with my airplane mode that refuses to turn off even when I use rfkill.
Does anyone have a solution for me? I am using ubuntu 20.04 on a lenovo thinkPad X200
Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you enable airplane mode? There’s usually a hardware shortcut via a function key on most laptops that toggles airplane mode on / off. And did you try via the settings menu?

Comment: "hardlocked" usually means a hardware or BIOS switch that Ubuntu cannot change. In most laptops, it's a keyboard combination. Ubuntu could change a "softlock."

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just had a look at that laptop online - there is in fact a hard on / off switch for wireless. I think it’s the side of the device (but may be the back) - there’s a USB port, then the VGA connector, then the Ethernet port, then another USB port, then *a physical slider switch for enabling / disabling wireless*.
[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much Will! it's finally work. I'm glad

Comment: @Akpé YEHOUNMEY - I'm very pleased to have helped. Do please accept the answer so it shows as having an accepted answer (click on the tick by the answer). Thanks!